# SQL Server : select from duplicate columns where date newest

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have inherited a SQL Server table in the (abbreviated) form of (includes sample data set):

```
| SID | name  | Invite_Date |    
|-----|-------|-------------|    
| 101 | foo   | 2013-01-06  |   
| 102 | bar   | 2013-04-04  |    
| 101 | fubar | 2013-03-06  |
```

I need to select all `SID`'s and the `Invite_date`, but if there is a duplicate `SID`, then just get the latest entry (by date).

So the results from the above would look like:

```
101 | fubar | 2013-03-06  
102 | bar   | 2013-04-04
```

Any ideas please.

N.B the `Invite_date` column has been declared as a `nvarchar`, so to get it in a date format I am using `CONVERT(DATE, Invite_date)`

Comment: try group by sid and select max(invite_date)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select t1.*
from your_table t1
inner join
(
  select sid, max(CONVERT(DATE, Invite_date)) mdate
  from your_table
  group by sid
) t2 on t1.sid = t2.sid and CONVERT(DATE, t1.Invite_date) = t2.mdate
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [ranking function](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx) like `ROW_NUMBER` or `DENSE_RANK` in a `CTE`:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT SID, name, Invite_Date,
           rn = Row_Number() OVER (PARTITION By SID
                                   Order By Invite_Date DESC)
   FROM dbo.TableName
)
SELECT SID, name, Invite_Date
FROM CTE 
WHERE RN = 1
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/fbe81/2/0)</kbd>

Use `Row_Number` if you want exactly one row per group and `Dense_Rank` if you want all last `Invite_Date` rows for each group in case of repeating max-`Invite_Date`s.

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
    SID,name,MAX(Invite_date) 
FROM 
    Table1
GROUP BY
    SID
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6b6f66/1